# Flickity - How can I remove last cell?

Tags: javascript, arrays, codepen, flickity

I'm having issues trying to eliminate the last cell in a Flickity slider, at 'ready' if possible. Could you please help me out? I am doing this in Vanilla JS.

This is the code so far (here's the CodePen link https://codepen.io/fran_dlt/pen/ZEbxmmb):

```
var flkty = new Flickity( '.carousel', {
  cellAlign: 'center',
  contain: false,
  groupCells: 1,
  on: {
          ready: function() {
            console.log('Flickity is ready');
      }
  }});

var cellCount = flkty.cells.length - 1;
console.log('Running ' + cellCount + ' slides');
flkty.remove(flkty.cells[cellCount]);
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should change last line to:
`flkty.remove(flkty.cells[cellCount].element);`

The remove() function accept jQuery object, Array of Elements, Element, or NodeList, not a cell object.
Here is the [Flickity remove document](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#remove)